# typesetting modulus operator, as in remainder

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

Is there a standard way to typeset the modulus operator (as in arithmetic remainder)? The percent sign (`%`) is often used by programming languages and mathematicians tend to use `mod`, but because of the romanization of `mod`, this notation can be confusing when used inline with text as in

```
So long as T mod n = 0 (i.e., the quantity is an integral multiple of n)...
```

I am currently using `$T\mod{}n=0$`, which places more space between the first argument and `mod` than between `mod` and the second argument.

Comment: You can omit the `{}`, just leave a space. For inline re-writing the sentenece and using "remainder" will read better. If the remainder of `T/n = 0 ...`.

Comment: `\mod` is defined by `amsmath` and it has an argument. But it's intended for things like `$a\equiv b\mod{n}$`, not for denoting the "remainder" operation. It's the "unparenthesized" version of `\pmod`, which is more commonly used.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Don't mix symbols and words like that: "If the remainder of $T/n=0$" would be parsed as talking about the remainder of the object $T/n=0$, which doesn't make sense. It's better to write "If the remainder of $T/n$ is zero" to avoid this.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Of course you right David. Easy for the mind to be tricked.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: the object $T/n$ is not the right one either; for example $3/3$ is $1$, so what is the remainder of $1$. We want discuss the remainder of $T$ modulo $n$, a function of two arguments.

Comment: I often just write something like: working modulo 7, we can clearly compute 2x5=10=3. Students always seem to get it, and it is pretty easy to write and to read. I think we overdo the complicated formulas when discussing modular arithmetic; just remember that the symbolic expression 10 has many meanings, so the meaning needs to be made clear by context, but not in every line of a calculation.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`\bmod` is designed for mod used as a binary op.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to actually use the percent symbol as an operator, you can use `\mathbin{\%}` to typeset it properly as a binary operator.