# \mod, quotient structures, and spacing

Tags: spacing, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [typesetting modulus operator, as in remainder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42866/typesetting-modulus-operator-as-in-remainder)

When `\mod` is used in

```
a \cong b \mod c
```

the extra space between `\mod` and what precedes it is appropriate.  But what if I want to write about the quotient structure `\mathbb R\mod {2\pi}`?  In that case `\mod` is more like a binary operator.  How should one code this to get something with spacing appropriate to the occasion?

Comment: `$$....$$` is depricated.  Use `\[...\]` instead.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Additionally to `\mod{<arg>}`, there’s `\bmod`, `\pmod{<arg>}` and `\pod{<arg>}`. Take a look at the [`amsmath` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) (`texdoc amsldoc`, page 18 (pdf 22), section 5.2).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The binary-operator version of `\mod` is `\bmod`.